# Controlling the intensity of bloom through the input field

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, post-processing

I'm trying to control the intensity of bloom through an input field, but when I enter the value in the input field on my mobile, the intensity doesn't change. I can't figure out what the problem is, can someone help me.

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.UI;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Linq;
 using TMPro;
 using UnityEngine.Events;
 using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
 using UnityEngine.Rendering.PostProcessing;
 
 public class BloomEffectController : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public PostProcessVolume postProcessVolume;
     public Bloom bloom;
     public TMP_InputField inputField;
 
 
     private void Start()
     {
         inputField = GetComponent<TMP_InputField>();
         postProcessVolume = GetComponent<PostProcessVolume>();
         postProcessVolume.profile.TryGetSettings(out bloom);
 
         
         inputField.onValueChanged.AddListener(SetBloomIntensity);
         
     }
 
     public void SetBloomIntensity(string value)
     {
         
         if (float.TryParse(value, out float intensity))
         {
             bloom.enabled.value = true;
             bloom.intensity.value = intensity;
            
         }
     }
 }
```

When I run the application on my android phone, and after scanning a picture the model and the canvas loads. So when I enter the value in the input field it should change the bloom intensity of the emissive material but absolutely nothing happens.
When I set the value of bloom in the start function of the above code, it works.

Comment: When is your ```SetBloomIntensity(string value)``` get called? And also make sure if the method is even getting called or not.